# Python- parse .txt files with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, text-files

I have the following as a .txt file

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}
{"g": 7, "h": 8, "i": 9}
```

How can I use python to open the file, and write a comma to separate each dictionary?
I.e. what regular expression can find every instance of "} {" and put a comma there?

(the real file is much larger (~10GB), and this issue prevents the file from being a syntactically correct JSON object that I can parse with json.loads())

Comment: Inserting a comma would not make this a valid JSON object, as you still need either a root object or put everything in an array `[ ... ]`

Comment: On another note, if every `{ ... }` pair is on its own line, it will possibly be easier to load every line on its own with `json.loads`

Comment: If each separate line is a JSON record, then it's pretty easy.  Print a '[' before the first line, print a "," before each succeeding line, and print a "]" to finish.

Comment: Are you sure you can load a 10GB structure as a single unit?  There may be a good reason why these are separate records.

Comment: Thanks all, this is very helpful.  Having iterated the first couple thousand lines of the actual document, it looks like each opening and closing curly brace is on its own line.  Would '\}\s*\{' as a regular expression identiy those occurances such that I can insert a comma at that index

Comment: The comment on size is a good point.  Would it work to batch the file at those intervals?  I.e. stick everything until the ''} {" partition as an element of a list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.join` with `','` as the delimeter, using a line-by-line file read in a generator expression. Then put `[]` around the contents to make it valid json.

```
import json
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    contents = '[' + ','.join(line for line in f) + ']'

data = json.loads(n)
```

This results in `data`

```
[
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6},
    {'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9}
]
```

Comment: Hopefully every `{ ... }` pair is on its own line :)

Comment: That may not be a happy solution with a 10GB file.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah I had a similar thought, going by their example, but if the structure is more complex they'd need to do something fancier than just a string join.

Comment: @TimRoberts If memory is an issue then every slightly naive solution will not be "a happy solution"

Comment: I suppose my example wasn't quite complex enough.  The actual quasi-json I'm trying to read is nested with 4 levels

Comment: @TimRoberts, do you know of a way to easily batch the file with partitions at "} {" instances?

Comment: ^in which case each batch would be in a dictionary format

Comment: My naive guess is that your records are actually separated by "}\n{", in which case it's very easy.  Read one line, decode it.  Read next line, decode it.